# How to prevent TreeItem selection?

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-8

I'm working with a `TreeTableView` (`JavaFX 8`). There are some tree nodes, which have to be disabled for selection. I had tried the selection event, but it doesn't work. Please find the below code for more information.

```
treeTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    {
        // utility node
        if(newValue.getValue() instanceof UtilityRoot )
        {
            return;
        }  
    }
);
```

How can I prevent some `TreeItems` from any mouse and keyboard selection?

Answer (score 1):

What you try to achieve cannot work as it simply adds a listener to be notified any time the selected item changes which is already too late in your case as you want to prevent the selection which happens before calling the listeners.

By default you can specify if you want the `SINGLE` or `MULTUPLE` selection mode using `treeTableView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(selectionMode)` and if you want to allow cell selection using `treeeTableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(enabled)`.

- `SelectionMode.SINGLE` and cell selection `enabled`: Enables selection of a single cell in the table.
- `SelectionMode.SINGLE` and cell selection `disabled`: Enables selection of a single row in the table.
- `SelectionMode. MULTUPLE` and cell selection `enabled`: Enables selection of several cells in several rows.
- `SelectionMode. MULTUPLE` and cell selection `disabled`: Enables selection of several rows in the table.

If it is not good enough for you, you will need to implement your own [`TreeTableViewSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel.html) and set it using [`setSelectionModel(TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel<S> value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html#setSelectionModel-javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView.TreeTableViewSelectionModel-).

Comment: Nicolas, thanks a lot for the help. Any chance to find code examples? It's not clear for me how exactly to override all `TreeTableViewSelectionModel` methods. There are no examples have been found on the web.

Comment: good question, I never had to do that so far and indeed doesn't seem to be easy, as example you should have a look to the source code of the JDK so for example http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.java#TreeTableView.TreeTableViewArrayListSelectionModel You could consider asking a new question for that