# JavaFx unselected TreeItem (TreeView)

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I made this treeView:

```
    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("roothidden");
    treeView.setRoot(root);
    treeView.setShowRoot(false);


    mainModel.getNumberOfCnx();


    if(mainModel.getNumberOfCnx()!=0){

        // parcourir pr avoir tt les noms des cnx
        for(int i = 1 ; i<=mainModel.getNumberOfCnx() ; i++){

             String cnx = mainModel.getCnxName(i);
             TreeItem<String> node = new TreeItem<>(cnx,new ImageView(env_icon));

             // ajouter les param
             TreeItem<String> host_node = new TreeItem<>(mainModel.getCnxHost(cnx),new ImageView(host_icon));
             TreeItem<String> port_node = new TreeItem<>(mainModel.getCnxPort(cnx),new ImageView(port_icon));
             TreeItem<String> user_node = new TreeItem<>(mainModel.getCnxUser(cnx),new ImageView(user_icon));
             TreeItem<String> db_node = new TreeItem<>(mainModel.getCnxDbName(cnx),new ImageView(db_icon));

             node.getChildren().addAll(host_node,port_node,user_node,db_node);

             root.getChildren().add(node);
        }
```

and I want all of host_node, port_node, user_node and db_node can't be selected(and not disabled).
How can I make it please?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: please check the image bellow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent TreeItem selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658392/how-to-prevent-treeitem-selection)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you try to achieve, I see three options:

1) Via the `TreeTableViewSelectionModel` as describe here:  [How to prevent TreeItem selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658392/how-to-prevent-treeitem-selection)

2) By using mouse transparent: `treeView.setMouseTransparent(true)`

3) By changing the selection colour to transparent via CSS

Comment: 4) Use a row factory that disables the rows corresponding to those items.